# Conflicts with multiple developers on one Visual Studio project with source control

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c#-express-2010

In my copy of a project's `.csproj` file i have a reference to an assembly:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\..\..\Components\Stackoverflow.NET Library\Stackoverflow Dot Net Library.csproj">
  <Project>{CFF8D7A7-D7D9-4460-84E6-E44FD9D33ACF}</Project>
  <Name>Stackoverflow Dot Net Library</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

Whenever another developers get's the version of that `.csproj` file, he has to change it to:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\..\Stackoverflow DotNet Library\Stackoverflow Dot Net Library.csproj">
  <Project>{CFF8D7A7-D7D9-4460-84E6-E44FD9D33ACF}</Project>
  <Name>Stackoverflow Dot Net Library</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

When he checks that in, i have to check it out and modify it back to:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\..\..\Components\Stackoverflow.NET Library\Stackoverflow Dot Net Library.csproj">
  <Project>{CFF8D7A7-D7D9-4460-84E6-E44FD9D33ACF}</Project>
  <Name>Stackoverflow Dot Net Library</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

And then another developer modifies the file to:

```
<ProjectReference Include="C:\Users\Jeff\Documents\Develop\VS2010\Stackoverflow.NET Library\Stackoverflow Dot Net Library.csproj">
  <Project>{CFF8D7A7-D7D9-4460-84E6-E44FD9D33ACF}</Project>
  <Name>Stackoverflow Dot Net Library</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

And then next checkin i have to change it back to:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\..\..\Components\Stackoverflow.NET Library\Stackoverflow Dot Net Library.csproj">
  <Project>{CFF8D7A7-D7D9-4460-84E6-E44FD9D33ACF}</Project>
  <Name>Stackoverflow Dot Net Library</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

Given that the library assembly:

- is another project in the same solution
- is built with the solution
- is not installed in the GAC (i.e. is built with the solution)
- is on a different path on different machines
- and Visual Studio does not support shared files

how can we have multiple developers working on the same solution?

**Note:** Visual C# Studio 2010 Express Edition

Comment: Are both projects in source control? In the same repository?

Comment: Then how come the relative paths are all different? Do they get checked out separately?

Comment: Each developer works at their own computer, with a local copy of the source (we don't all work at the same computer)

Comment: Didn't expect you to... But if the projects are layed out a certain way in source control, why is this not reflected uniformly when checking out?

Comment: @Oded Can't really force everyone to create a folder on their computer called `C:\Users\Ian\Documents\Visual Studio 2010`. i mean you could, but not every computer even *has* a `C:\` drive.

Comment: True, but for _relative paths_ that won't make a difference. So long as they are in the same _relation_ to each other, things are good.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6630/discussion-between-oded-and-ian-boyd)