# How to handle in-filesystem references in a project with multiple developers?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

We have a project that has references to libraries located in different directories on each development machine. Every time a new development machine is used, we need to manually re-add certain libraries in multiple projects, and we would like to fix this issue before the problem becomes larger.

Currently, manually re-adding references causes every development machine adds its own HintPath to the .csproj file, which results in the .csproj file looking like this:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.Text, Version=0.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Extensions\ml2dtxdz.42m\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.Text.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Extensions\tpvugvu1.kcm\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.Text.dll</HintPath>
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Extensions\wcunwe5f.4dt\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.Text.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

The idea is to copy these libraries to a directory relative to the solution, such that the .csproj simplifies to:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.Text, Version=0.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages_extra\VisualStudio12.0\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

This moves referenced libraries to our source control, simplifies the .csproj file, and eliminates the process of re-adding references on each new development machine. So far this approach works great.

**My questions**: Are there any reasons why we shouldn't be doing this? Is there a better way of solving this problem?

*Let's assume that all developers have the same operating system, the same version of Visual Studio and the same CPU architecture.*

This question is similar to unanswered [Conflicts with multiple developers on one Visual Studio project with source control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825258/conflicts-with-multiple-developers-on-one-visual-studio-project-with-source-cont)

We also tried setting per-user **Reference Paths** in project properties, but Visual Studio never seemed to pick up on these hints.

Comment: have you considered using the command line mklink to create links to which you reference in your solution? - you could create a batch file to create the relevant links that could be customised to each dev's environment. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx

Comment: That's a good idea! We'll look into this if current approach breaks. Having each developer create their own set of shortcuts is not as seamless, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the approach of uploading all needed references to a CVS and configuring the projects to reference them always worked great.

Thanks to this, the whole solution is ready to compile just after initial checkout. This dramatically reduces setup time for new developers, or new machines. Also, managing these references is easy - if your commit needs a new version of some component, then also this commit will stand for itself. After update, the change will be transparent for other developers working on other parts of the system.

In large projects, minimizing infrastructural concerns saves great amount of time.

Comment: In the solution I am currently working on I created a project to hold the external dlls (dependences) and then reference those in the projects in the solution. I used a project as that meant getting latest on the project got all the files from source control reducing the need for sending files to everyone and telling them if any had been updated.

Answer (score 3):

1) Perfectly valid to do this.  I have worked on multiple projects with 3rd part assemblies in a folder relative to the solution. As long as the folder is pulled down from source control each time it should work a treat.  If this lives above your solution dont forget to let people know this when they do "gets" so they dont miss it.

2) An alternative with more critical mass/in a larger organisation may be to use your own Nuget server such as ProGet.

Comment: I like your second point. All references that worked right out of the box were references handled by NuGet.